# Why won't my image display in firefox?

Tags: html

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/hjfqvgey/) but the image doesn't display in firefox. Why not? The html is

```
<div id="message1" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable flyover flyover-centered">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
  <strong></strong> User added
</div>

<!-- Menubar -->

<div id="menubar">
    <div id="menubarcentercontainer">
        <div id="menubarleft">
        </div>
        <div id="menubarright">
            <div id="menubaruserinfo" class="menubaritem">
                <p><a href="javascript:showLoginBox();">Sign In or Sign Up</a></p>          
            </div>

            <div class="menubaritem">
                <p>Get Onacci</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<img id="top-header" src="https://wwwe.onacci.com/onacci.png">
<form id="searchbox" action="connect.php" method="POST">
    <div class="control-group" style="float:left;">
        <div class="controls" style="float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="input-xlarge">
            <p class="help-block">Please provide your E-mail</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add me to waiting list</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try opening up dev tools and seeing if any errors arise. Also, disable any ad-block extensions.

Comment: It shows up when I test it in Firefox (v. 40.0.2).

Comment: Same here... with v39

Comment: For me, directly accessing the image through Firefox gives me a "This Connection is Untrusted" warning. If your computer is also flagging the connection like this, that's probably why the image isn't showing. (Adding a security exception allows it to appear in the JSFiddle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an "e" on your `www` url request(image path).
Also, the image URL is untrusted and firefox will keep blocking the image source url.

Comment: It's supposedly meant to be that way, as you get an image back when you browse to that URL. Using `wwwe` as a subdomain name is just as valid as any other name, only a bit unusual.

Answer (score 2):

Try requesting the image URL in a new window.

It's classed as an untrusted connection by default in Firefox and therefore the image won't download and display.

[image]

Comment: That is the problem. When you add an exception the image shows up.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing up on Firefox v40. However, if it is an issue of "This Connection is Untrusted" error, then better you refer to this solution at official Firefox support forum: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-untrusted-error-message